# What are the essentials to getting fit?

Tags: weight-loss, programs, tips

There are hundreds of weight loss and 'get fit' programs out there that it becomes an overwhelming and daughnting task in choosing one that is helpful. I undersand that everyone is different in the dynamics of 'losing weight' or 'getting fit'. What I'm wondering is this: Are there common factors that affect all of us in the quest of becoming fit?  If so, what are these common factors? Are there some that are more important than others?

Comment: eating healthy and balance cardio with weight lifts are pretty general.

Comment: That would be an interesting topic for a blog post ;-)

Comment: @IvoFlipse I know ;P

Comment: @IvoFlipse should this become a community wiki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some components of fitness improve both your performance and health, and others only improve your performance (power training, agility training, etc.). I would say the most essential components of a fitness program are the ones that improve your health. These are generally listed as:

- Cardiovascular endurance: achieved by doing things like running, aerobics, swimming, cardio machines, etc.
- Muscular strength and endurance: achieved by doing resistance training (lifting weights), sprint training, and some styles of yoga.
- Flexibility: achieved by stretching, yoga, martial arts, and some styles of dance.
- Body Composition: achieved by balancing your diet and exercise keep body fat and muscle levels within the healthy range.

So, the most basic exercise program should include some cardio, some resistance training , some stretching, and some attention to your diet. Cardio and resistance training contribute to weight loss. During cardio, you burn quite a few calories, and weight training causes an increase in muscle mass, which raises your metabolic rate so you burn more calories at rest. Different people have different opinions about which is more important for weight loss. I'd say diet is more important than either though. It can take over 20 minutes to burn 250 calories, but less than a minute to [eat them all back](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calories/mars-mars-bar-7149738).

Answer (score 1):

My number one essential for getting fit is being realistic. If you go on a proper diet and exercise regime, which is a given, you will have setbacks and failures. Accepting those and then pushing yourself to get back into your diet and regime ASAP will do you wonders.

You need to be determined and realize that it takes about a month of very hard discipline.  After a month you'll start seeing some changes and things will become easier on your brain as you won't need as much focus to eat well and exercise.

That has been my experience when dieting and exercising.